# How do I communicate with hundred of devices over internet?

Tags: networking, internet

I'm starting a personal project where I will deploy some Internet connected devices (maybe hundred of them). I need to be able to get data and communicate with this devices through my computer or my phone, but the problem is I can't rely on the public IP address because it can change.

With this problem in mind, I though of using some services like [noip](http://www.noip.com/), but the problem is I will have to pay a lot of money for a unique IP for every device I have every year.

The second approach is to deploy a server with a know and fixed IP address using [noip](http://www.noip.com/) and every device should connect to the server (we know the server IP). Every device will have an unique ID, so the server will have a database with all this IDs and their corresponding current IP address, if the IP address changes, the device will simply send the new IP to the server with his unique ID. So on this way I only have to keep a single fixed IP address but I have to add a server capable of handling all the connections.

Is there any other approach am I missing? I'm not a networking guy so this kind of things are really new to me.

Comment: dyndns is a DNS service that you can setup to automatically change to the new ip address. Other than that, companies usually pay a lot of money for a static ip address.

Comment: Just keep devices connected to your service all the time. If IP changes, your device will have to reconnect anyway, so you do need any fancy logic. Another approach is to use already existing infrastructure - IRC, ICQ, Skype, Reddit etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can deploy programs on the devices which can connect to your server you're right.

But please be careful of security topics as you don't want anybody else "registering" to your server and also to get access to your machines. Also if you make your machines "connectible" it could lead to major issues.

All depends on what do you want to do - this is missing from your description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I protect from other devices from registering to the server? Do you know where I can read about this?

Comment: you can start here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/ensuring-a-web-service-only-processes-requests-from-specific-computers

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar in the past using a VPN.

Without any details of your devices I don't know to what their capabilities are, I was running a small number machines running Linux (Raspberry Pi's actually)

You can configure the remote devices to connect to the VPN server at start up, once they're connected they will appear as if on a private LAN. You can then connect your computer / phone to the VPN to access the remote machines.

The remote machines are making an outbound connection to the VPN server so it doesn't matter if their IP changes, you will see them as local addresses.

In my particular case I hosted an [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) virtual server on Amazon AWS for a small monthly cost - they have OpenVPN in their image library. There are Linux and Windows clients for connecting to OpenVPN too.

Comment: Nice! I have been reading about VPNs and seems a great solution. However it's not straightforward for all the platforms (Windows and Android)